# Fortran Compiler

Tags: android, fortran

I am developing an android app on a Mac.
Does anyone know of a fortran compiler for android???
I was going to call some fortran routines from a C routine. Then wrap the C routine with a java class and use the JNI to do this.

BUT, I can't get the fortran code compiled.

Comment: That's a great question! I would try using `f2c` an open-source Fortran to C converter. Once you have the code in C, you can do the rest. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Ya I just stumbled upon this. Sounds good. Ill need to get it going on my Mac here. Ill post the outcome.

Comment: Well it looks like Apple discontinued the f2c version for Mac. Annoying. I suppose I can try their Visual Basic version.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried it myself, but people have successfully built gfortran for Android. See e.g. http://specificimpulses.blogspot.com/2012/08/something-borrowed-android-fortran.html and http://danilogiulianelli.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-build-gcc-fortran-cross-compiler.html .

If the only reason for your C code is to wrap the Fortran code, maybe you could instead just use ISO_C_BINDING (which gfortran supports), and have JNI call that directly (with ISO_C_BINDING you can make code in Fortran that is ABI compatible with C).

Comment: That would work assuming I had a fortran compiler provided by the android NDK but I don't. Unfortunately they only provide a C and C++ compiler.....not ideal as I have a lot of f90 routines.

Comment: @Fra: My understanding is that since the official Android NDK doesn't provide a Fortran compiler, people have built it themselves per the instructions in the links above. Doesn't that solve your problem then?

Comment: I was looking for something else, but the idea of having a Fortran compiler on my phone is just a wonderful thought.  I wonder if there are any card readers that can work with a USB OTG cable?  Better still, what about a Fortran compiler for an Arduino?