# How do I execute a Fortran based program in Android

Tags: android, fortran

I have coded a program in Fortran an works perfectly in Windows, my question is if there is any way I can use it in Android.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27846579/5733111) .. This might help

Comment: Yes but I just need a way to use my program in android. Not want to install compilers there, I mean, is there anyway I can find an emulator or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to just make a comment, but I will answer the concern you raise of "not wanting to install compilers" to build fortran programs for android. On pretty much any operating system there are no default compilers for any language, so you have to install compilers (luckily for fortran on windows you even have a lot of options). For Android, right now, you have only one choice. That is to build your own custom version of the NDK gcc cross toolchain and force it to build gfortran and libgfortran. As of right now, gcc has been deprecated in the toolchain. Soon that won't even be an option. I have recently built the previous version of the NDK with gfortran using the following link:
https://github.com/buffer51/android-gfortran

The other problem you're going to run into is that depending on what kind of application you have on windows (command line, gui, webapp, etc.), you're not going to be able to run it on a typical android tablet or phone because there is no command line interface by default (you'll probably have to root the device to get one). The easiest way to develop a usable android app is to write a Java app (using the SDK), and then use JNI to interface with a fortran "library". Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way to compile and use your program on Android, and soon even the complicated ways (building a custom compiler) will get even more complicated.

Comment: There are some alternative toolchains which preserve GCC, like CrystaX. They don't support Fortran, of course, one would have to hack it oneself.

Comment: Yes! I love Crystax (other than fortran), I didn't think of mentioning them. Since Android has deprecated gcc from the NDK, I think either funding them to include fortran (which I'd love to do), or to figure out how to apply what's been done by "buffer51" to the Crystax NDK. It'd be awesome to have gcc 6 on every platform I use.